# OData exception with especific string

Tags: html, vb.net, linq, api, odata

I have a trouble when i try to search in a container. My code is it:

```
Dim strtextbox As String = "<p>This B2C tenant must be linked to an active Azure subscription for communication, support and billing. <a href='https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-how-to-enable-billing' target='_blank' aria-label='Learn More - This B2C tenant must be linked to an active Azure subscription for communication, support and billing.'>Learn More</a></p>\r\n<p><b>If your Subscription status is No Subscription, please link this B2C tenant to an Azure subscription,</b></p>\r\n<p>\r\n    <ol>\r\n        <li><a href='#menu/account'>Switch Directories</a> to the location of your target Azure subscription</li>\r\n        <li>Under Marketplace, search for and select 'B2C'</li>\r\n        <li>Select Create to link this B2C Tenant to a subscription</li>\r\n    </ol>\r\n</p>\r\n<p><b>If your Subscription status is Warned, Suspended or Deleted, navigate to the linked Subscription for more information,</b></p>\r\n<p>\r\n    <ol>\r\n        <li><a href='#menu/account'>Switch Directories</a> to the location of the Azure subscription linked to this B2C Tenant</li>\r\n        <li>Under All Resources click on your B2C Tenant resource</li>\r\n        <li>Under Essentials select your subscription and review Subscription status</li>\r\n    </ol>\r\n</p>"

Dim res = cont.Entity.Where(Function(b) String.Compare(b.FullSourceString, strtextbox, True) = 0)

For Each j As Entity in res

     do something
End For
```

Well, the problem is with that string and others html large strings. The odata.client "An error ocurred while processing this request" throws me an exception. If i modify 2 or 3 things from the string, this works. The uri works fine with that strings. The problem i think is with OData protocol.

Some help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to escape any single quotes by doubling them up.

```
strtextbox = strtextbox.Replace("'", "''")
```